# How to re-write an nfc tag (rfid/microchip) which is READ-only

Tags: nfc, rfid, microchip

how to rewrite an nfc tag (microchip). when is scanned whith the NFC Tools app their characteristcs are:

**Tag type: ISO 14443-4
Technologies available: TypeA, IsoDep
Serial number: XXXXXXXXXX
Size: 15 Bytes
Writable: No**

Record - Text where are the followings specs:
Format:
**NFC Well Known (0x01)
Defined by RFC 2141, RFC 3986**

**Encoding: UTF-8

Payload: 11 bytes**

I even paid for writeable mode on the NFC Tools App on my iPhone and on the write mode an error is occured: "This NFC tag is not supported", it works only to read it.

So, is there a possibility to unlock it and to write/modify the tag type, technologies available, content info, or there is no any chances to do that?

Thank you!

I tried to use NFC Tools App on the Write mode with a 3 usd paid on the app but is not working. error occured "This NFC tag is not supported". It works only on the READ MODE.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change a Tag that is marked as Read Only the NFC spec says that making a Tag that conforms to the NFC specification read only is irreversible and this is usually protected in the Tag hardware.